# can't run sh script from crontab

Tags: scripting, cron, firefox

my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
if pgrep -x  "firefox" >/dev/null
then
    return
else
    firefox &
fi
```

my crontab:

```
* * * * * /home/jesuscrew77/sc.sh
```

It runs manually but doesn't start with crontab. what is wrong?

Comment: firefox being a graphical browser, it's likely missing a `$DISPLAY`

Comment: can you confirm via the cron logs that the cron job is, indeed, firing or not?

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes it'is firing Jul 20 15:17:01 jesuscrew77 CRON[6277]: (jesuscrew77) CMD (export DISPLAY=:0  /home/jesuscrew77/sc.sh) did i correctly add DISPLAY?